# React + Enzyme - Unable to find anything in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I've created a very basic functional component in React (using Typescript).

However when I go to test it - I keep getting received `{}` when I ask it gather the `div`s:

So the component looks like:

```
export const TestComponent: React.FC<FakeInt> = () => {
    return (
        <div>ARE YOU WORKING
           <div>Checking here</div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

along with

```
interface FakeInt {}
```

And the test:

```
it('It does something', () => {
        let wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent />);

        expect(wrapper.find("div")).toEqual("")
});
```

(I've just put equal to `""` - as I'd expect to see something received/just want to confirm its actually finding those divs)

If I had `console.log(wrapper.debug());` I actually see the wrapper's content which is strange.

The version of Jest I'm using came with my React app.

And another piece of info. `expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();` creates a snapshot file which also contains an empty object `{}`

Any ideas what's up here/why this wouldn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used enzyme much ( I prefer react-testing-library ), but I think you have to mount functional components for them to work with tests. Again, not 100% on this.

Comment: Tried that with no success.

Answer (score 0):

please provide the version of enzyme you are using, also for react you should use enzyme-adapter-react-16 (or what ever version of react you are using)

in the test:

```
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

than it should work